# How to change the default home activity for SherlockActionBar, avoiding the back arrow in main activity after login

Tags: android, android-intent, actionbarsherlock, android-lifecycle

I have the following order of activity lauching:

LoginActivity (the LAUNCHER) -> MainActivity

The LoginActivity is calling the MainActivity using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP );
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

The MainAcitivity defines "HomeAsUpEnabled":

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and LoginActivity is checked with noHistory:

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

I want HomeAsUpEnabled from that activity (ignoring only the login activity). The MainActivity should become the new home (instead of LoginActivity).

I would like to avoid the MainActivity has the "back arrow" shown in the SherlockActionBar. Is it possible?

Regards,

Rafael

Comment: Set `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);`

Comment: vikram, but I want homeasupenabled from that activity (ignoring only the login activity). The MainActivity should become the new home (instead of LoginActivity)

Comment: Well, the intent flags you are setting should ensure that a click on `back arrow` behaves the way you want. Does the arrow launch `LoginActivity`?

Comment: I believe it is. However the LoginActivity checks that it is logged in and launch the MainActivity again.